# How to show that the exponential map of a lie algebra maps to the lie group?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I am having trouble seeing how the exponential map takes elements from a lie algebra and maps them to the lie group. I believe the map is Given by exp(tX) where X is an element of the lie algebra. I think I have to show that it is equal to a path through the lie group, but I have no idea where to start with this.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathrm{exp}(tX)$? Are you just considering matrix Lie groups/algebras, and thinking of $X$ as a matrix, so that $\mathrm{exp}(tX)$ is the usual matrix exponential, given by the power series formula?

Comment: It depends on your definitions.  Often the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is *defined* to be the set of $X$ such that $\exp(tX) \in G$ for all $t$.

Comment: I don't know that there's a lot to understand. Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to G$ be a one-parameter subgroup of $G$ with $\gamma ' (0) = X \in \frak{g}$. Then $\exp(X) = \gamma(1) \in G$ by definition. So $\exp(X)$ lives in $G$ by definition. The more curious thing is that $\exp(X)$ is well-defined according to this definition.

Comment: OK I see it now, I wasn't paying attention to the exp(X) = gamma(1), thank you.